# Proper way to assign variables in a class function to avoid PEP error E501 in python

Tags: python, pep8, pep

I call a function from a class object like:

```
class_name.function(
    var1=1,
    var2=10,
    this_is_a_long_variable_name=this_is_another_long_variable,
    var4=15
)
```

If I do this the third line I get a PEP 8 error E501: line too long.
If I change the above code to the following:

```
class_name.function(
    var1=1,
    var2=10,
    this_is_a_long_variable_name=\
        this_is_another_long_variable,
    var4=15
)
```

I get for the third line `this_is_a_long_variable_name=\` PEP 8 error E502. The backslash is redundant between brackets and PEP 8 error E251 unexpected spaces around keyword. For the fourth line `this_is_another_long_variable,` I get PEP 8 error E131 continuation line unaligned for hanging indent.

What is the proper way of calling the object function to avoid the aforementioned errors?

Comment: Pep8 error checking is not part of python itself; you're getting these error messages from some static analysis tool, which itself is possibly embedded inside your IDE.  Let us know what tool you're using, so we have a better idea of how it works.  It sounds like you might solve E502 and E251 simply by removing the \.  Maybe that will magically solve E131 as well.  None of us can be certain until we know what tool is generating that error.

Comment: I use Sublime Text 3 as an editor and on top of it I use the anaconda plugin http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/